# Can't start chrome driver via selenium in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a problem. I have an application that should run on the linux server where is not GUI I want to run it headless. On my local machine everything works fine but on the server I have a problem and I don't know why, yesterday it worked but currently I'm getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.07 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'vps334949', ip: '92.222.74.219', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor54.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
```

Be fore start application I run these commands:

```
Xvfb :40 &
Xvfb :40 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -extension RANDR &
export DISPLAY=:40
```

But it is not woriking now, could you please somene help where should be the problem?

This is how I run web driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/chrome/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747). Check that you are doing the prereqs for linux.  I got this working in my last job because PhantomJS wasn't behaving correctly for some JavaScript that development wanted to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to start the selenium server using `xvfb-run` command. Execute the below command in the terminal first and then start the execution of the scripts.

```
xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.jar
```

Comment: Hi Thanks!! I run these commands for my app
1) xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar &
2) Xvfb :40 &
3) export DISPLAY=:40 
4) java -jar myapp.jar &
And now everything is working again!!

Answer (score 1):

I found that selenium driver is not needed when I run my app like this way:

```
xvfb-run -a java -jar my_jar.jar
```

it works!